# filtering a matrix values based on numeric threshold

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix of values called data.mat

```
       [1,]     [2,]   [3,]
[1,]   0.001    0.03   0.003
[2,]   0.100    0.02   0.001
```

I wish to keep all values that are below 0.01, so I tried:

```
> (data.mat < 0.01)
```

which retunred:

```
       [1,]    [2,]     [3,]
[1,]   TRUE    FALSE    TRUE
[2,]   FALSE   FALSE    TRUE
```

But I want to get the actual values instead of getting logical arguments. I also tried:

```
as.numeric(data.mat < 0.01)
```

But this returned 0 and 1. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: `data.mat[(data.mat < 0.01)]`

Comment: If you want to replace other values as 0 in original matrix, `data.mat[data.mat >=0.01] <- data.mat[data.mat >=0.01]*0` or `NA`, `data.mat[data.mat >=0.01] <- NA^data.mat[data.mat >=0.01]` or `is.na(data.mat) <- data.mat >=0.01`